# How to check if a method was not invoked with mockk?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockk, mockk-verify

I need to check if a method was not invoked in my unit tests. This is an example test I did that checks if the method was invoked and it works perfectly fine:

```kotlin
@Test
fun viewModel_selectDifferentFilter_dispatchRefreshAction() {
    val selectedFilter = FilterFactory.make()
    val event = GroceriesAisleFiltersUiEvent.SelectFilter(
        filter = selectedFilter,
        refreshListAction = mockk()
    )
    every { event.refreshListAction(selectedFilter) } just runs
    viewModel.dispatchViewAction(event)
    verify { event.refreshListAction(selectedFilter) }
}
```

For that I'm using the mockk's `verify` function to check if the method is being invoked.

Is there a way to check, using `mockk`, that this method has not been invoked? In short I need to complete the code below with this check in place of the comment:

```kotlin
@Test
fun viewModel_selectSameFilter_notDispatchRefreshAction() {
    val selectedFilter = viewModel.viewState.value.selectedFilter
    val event = GroceriesAisleFiltersUiEvent.SelectFilter(
        filter = selectedFilter,
        refreshListAction = mockk()
    )
    every { event.refreshListAction(selectedFilter) } just runs
    viewModel.dispatchViewAction(event)
    // TODO: verify if method's not invoked
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you want to verify that your method was not called, you can verify that it was called exactly 0 times:

```
verify(exactly = 0) { event.refreshListAction(any()) }
```

Or, in this case where your `event.refreshListAction` is the mock, you can equivalently write the following to verify that the mock was not called at all:

```
verify { event.refreshListAction wasNot Called }
```

**EDIT**

It seems that the mock in the question being itself a function (or something else with an `invoke` operator function) leads to a lot of confusion. For the difference between `verify(exactly = 0)` and a verify with `wasNot Called`, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75028370/15375588), where the mock is a simple object.

Comment: this doesn't work with a mocked navController. Edit: So, for some reason, only the first one works with navController and not the second one.

Comment: Can confirm this. First works, second doesn't.

Comment: In the second case it should be using :: `event::refreshListAction`

Comment: verify { event.refreshListAction wasNot called } cannot be used with methods. wasNot can only be used for checking that a mock as a whole was not called. It cannot be used for checking that a method was not called.

Comment: @JohanPaul Yes, please note the line `refreshListAction = mockk()` in the question. `event.refreshListAction` is not a method of the mock, but it is the mock.

Answer (score 2):

I tried with `verify { mockObj.myMethod(any()) wasNot called }` and the test failed even when the method of the mock is not called. Then read the comments and saw that one from @Johan Paul I will try to add more explanation:

If you want to assert that a particular method is not called you should sue:

```
verify(exactly = 0) { mockObj.myMethod(any()) }
```

When you need to assert that the mock is not called at all, us should use:

```
verify { mockObj wasNot called }
```

This is applicable only if the `mockObj` is the mocked object it self. Like this:

```
 val mockObj = mockk() // or mockk(relaxed = true)
```

In your case answer given by Karsten Gabriel, works because it refers to the mock.