# Mockk verify fails when checking called and wasNot called

Tags: kotlin, testing, mockk, kotest

I am trying to verify that a function was not called using the following:

```
verify {
    managementService.deleteUser(any()) wasNot Called
}
```

That verification fails with the message:

> Verification failed: call 1 of 1:
> ManagementService(#11).deleteUser(any())) was not called.

If I invert the verification to this:

```
verify {
    managementService.deleteUser(any())
}
```

I still receive the same failure message.

There are other functions on `ManagementService` that pass `wasNot Called` just fine.

Why would my verification failing for `wasNot Called`, while the error message says the failure is because it was not called? And why would inverting the check produce the same error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a method was not invoked with mockk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71680808/how-to-check-if-a-method-was-not-invoked-with-mockk)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`wasNot Called` is not used to verify that a specific function call has not been made, but that an entire mock was never called, like this:

```
verify {
    managementService wasNot Called
}
```

If you want to verify that `deleteUser` was not called with any argument, you can verify that the call happened exactly zero times:

```
verify(exactly = 0) {
    managementService.deleteUser(any())
}
```

Comment: This solves it. I see it in the docs now too (https://notwoods.github.io/mockk-guidebook/docs/mocking/verify/#verifying-that-a-function-is-never-called). That didn't jump out at me before because I'm pretty new to Kotlin and Mockk and I was mimicking other existing tests. I'm still a little puzzled because the existing tests passed. For example, `verify { managementService.createUser(any()) }` passed verification. I initially included my original check in that same block but moved it to its own verify block to troubleshoot. Both cases, `createUser(any())` passes but `deleteUser(any())` fails.