# Why is mockk executing a method when I'm checking for not invoked scenario?

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, junit, mockk, mockk-verify

I have a scenario like

```
fun someMethod() {
   try {
       val response = callApi.method()
       val output = processResponse(response)
   } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
   }
}
```

Now I'm testing for the scenario when callApi.method() throws an exception and the method `processResponse()` is not invoked. It is working as expected but mockk is failing

```
verify(exactly = 0) { processResponse(any()) }
verify { processResponse(any()) wasNot Called }
```

with this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null
```

My question is that why mockk is trying to execute the processResponse() method with a null response from any() when I'm just verifying that the method is not invoked? Are there any other ways to avoid this error? Thanks

Comment: I think you are not mocking your class under test properly.  Please share more of your code

Comment: Are you sure that `wasNot Called` is what you want to use here? Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75028370/15375588